# Click on tag and view only picture with the same tag

Tags: java, android

I wouldlike to when I click on tag of one of my picture to view only pictures with the same tag.

In this picture an example of what I want :

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTIOe.jpg)

```
private void initRecyclerView(){
         mImageUrls.add("https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4636/25316407448_de5fbf183d_o.jpg");
        mNames.add("Havasu Falls");
        mtags.add("#Sun");

        mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/0h2gm1ix6p501.jpg");
        mNames.add("Mahahual");
        mtags.add("#Sun");


        mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/k98uzl68eh501.jpg");
        mNames.add("Frozen Lake");
        mtags.add("#Winter");

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_public);
        MyRecyclerViewAdapter MyRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls, mtags);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager RecyclerGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(RecyclerGridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(MyRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must...

1. Create a model/pojo class to store details like url, name and tag.
2. Create two list of your pojo class. (ArrayList) one for all data and one for filtered data.
3. When user clicks on tag...filter your data with that clicked tag and display that list in a recyclerView.

In short use 'Filterable' for recyclerview see this https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/

Comment: Thank you I will check that !